# How to pass data to a child and render it in the child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to pass an array from a parent to a child but render/output it in the child and not in the parent. In the tutorials which I found I am only able to render the array in the parent. So for example I have the following:

**child**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{tile.name}} {{formattedPoints}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            tile: {
                required: true,
                type: Object
            }
        },
        
        computed: {
            formattedPoints() {
                return this.tile[0].name = 5
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**parent**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <User v-for="tile in tileMenu" :key="tile.id" :tile="tile" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import User from './Home.vue'
    import { ref } from 'vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            User
        },

        setup() {
            const tileMenu = ref([
                { id: 1, name: 'tile1' },
                { id: 2, name: 'tile2' },
            ])
            return { tileMenu }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In this exapmle I would make the output with the parent but I like to have it with the child. In my thought process this should be possible because I pass the array anyway to the child component and if I call it like this

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{tile[0].name}} 
    </div>
</template>
```

it should give me the output with the child component. But that outputs nothing. How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to achieve here: you are indeed passing the `tile` (not the array, but an element of the array) into your child component. What isn't working?

Comment: @Terry My goal is to have the following structure 

parent component: includes a standard array
---child1: output the array in format1:
---child2: output the array in format2

Comment: @Terry But I cant output this element of the array only within the parent component

Comment: First because of your for-loop in parent, the id in the array tileMenu need to be different because you use it as key. And key is unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose you that (and id need to be unique because it's your key in the for loop)

parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <User :tileMenu="tileMenu" /> <!--pass all array-->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import User from "./Home.vue";

const tileMenu = [
  { id: 1, name: "tile1NAME" },
  { id: 2, name: "tile2NAME" },
];

export default {
  components: {
    User,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tileMenu: tileMenu,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

child:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="tile in tileMenuChild" :key="tile.id">
      {{ tile.name }} with id {{ tile.id }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    tileMenu: Array,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tileMenuChild: this.tileMenu,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223326/discussion-on-answer-by-zerbene-how-to-pass-data-to-a-child-and-render-it-in-the).